# What does TMUBMUSD10Y stand for? (U.S. 10 Year Treasury Note)

Tags: united-states, bonds, fixed-income, treasury, quotes

MarketWatch, WSJ, and Barrons all list the U.S. 10 Year Treasury Note using the symbol **TMUBMUSD10Y**.

1. What type of ticker/symbol is this?
2. What does **TMUBM**USD10Y stand for?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect we won't be able to get an authoritative answer, but here is a guess:

- T = treasury
- MU = ?
- BM = bond market
- USD = US dollar
- 10Y = year

I'll make this a community wiki so others can update.

Comment: "TMU" stands for Treasury Market Unit.